# How to get the pattern of Number Format of a specific locale?

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting

I have a simple question:

How to get the pattern used to format a number using `NumberFormat` created for a specific locale as shown  below:

```
import java.util.Locale;

Locale aLocale = new Locale("fr","CA");
NumberFormat numberFormat=NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(aLocale);
```

Here I want to know the pattern used to format a number in `French` language and the country of `Canada`.

For e.g. :

a number `123456.7890` is converted into `123 456,789` after formatting it means pattern may be `# ###,###` for above mentioned locale.

Comment: What do you want exactly? The string representation of it?

Comment: No, I want to know the patten defined for this number format. For e.g. like this `#,###.00`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subclasses DecimalFormat and ChoiceFormat have a method toPattern(), so you must check using instanceof and call toPattern()

```
  String pattern = null;
   if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
       pattern = ((DecimalFormat)numberFormat).toPattern();
   }
```

Consider DecimalFormat.toLocalizedPattern() too

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat` is an interface so there can be multiple implementations.

```
public String getPattern(NumberFormat numberFormat) {
    if(numberFormat instanceof java.text.DecimalFormat)
        return ((java.text.DecimalFormat)numberFormat).toPattern();
    if(numberFormat instanceof java.text.ChoiceFormat)
        return ((java.text.ChoiceFormat)numberFormat).toPattern();
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown NumberFormat implementation");
}
```

Please note that this will work today, but may break in the future when other implementations are added.