# How to get default date pattern in java?

Tags: java, date, formatting

```
public class DefaultDateFormatPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}
```

The output is: `Thu Jan 08 10:52:56 IST 2015`

Is there any method in Java to get the pattern of the date it is showing ?

Comment: By "pattern", do you mean a pattern string that can be used with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: If you mean the current default platform date, then you should use `Locales` and `getDefault()`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for a moment in time. The format produced by its `toString` method is in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`.

Answer (score 7):

According to Java 8 `toString()` method of `Date` class the format is: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`.

Comment: Correct (not that we should bother since in 2019 we should no longer use the `Date`  class).

Answer (score 4):

You can try [SimpleDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toLocalizedPattern%28%29) or [SimpleDateFormat.toPattern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toPattern%28%29) to get the pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat();
System.out.println(format.toLocalizedPattern());
System.out.println(format.toPattern());
```

Pass locale to get the locale specific pattern.

[Read similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513607/how-to-get-the-pattern-of-number-format-of-a-specific-locale)

Comment: The SimpleDateFormat constructor needs the pattern with locale. But I want to know pattern from the date it is printing for my locale.

Comment: Look at `Date.toString()` method in source code and look what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

 DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("DDD", Locale.getDefault());

 String day = d.format(rightNow.getTime());
```

You can use the overloaded constructor of `SimpleDateFormat` to get the current default use `Locale.getDefault()` in the 2nd argument..
Check the [SimpleDateFormat Api Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to get whatever the date format you want.
The default format of SimpleDateFormat is

> d/M/yy h:mm a

you can set the way you want.

Eg.

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```